# Got warning from enavto theme check plugin about custom css

Tags: css, wordpress, escaping, sanitization

I am working on wordpress theme and confuse to echoed custom css.I don`t get a exact way to sanitize custom css.Please help me!! how to escape custom css??

```
WARNING: Found echo ($ in the file functions.php. Possible data validation issues found. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered.
    Line 222: echo ($css_output);
```

Thankyou!!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: @ParthShah Still not get a exact answer to add a custom css with escape function.

Comment: what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the function `esc_attr`, check the following example, I have used the function `implode` to extract the array and then safely escaped it with `esc_attr`.

```
$css_output = ['.hello-world { color: red }', '.test { font-size: 12px; }'];

echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $css_output));
```

** Updated **

For ThemeForest submission, you should use [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style), in your case this should be the right code.

`wp_add_inline_style('your-wp-style', $css_output);`

Make sure to add the inline style to one of your CSS files that are already enqueued.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but Css is not in the form of array

Comment: The array was only as an example, using only `echo esc_attr($css_output)` will output the same result.

Comment: echo esc_attr($css_output) show all css on screen not include at backend.